# I don't understand this Javascript?

Tags: javascript

Can someone walk me thru this example and why it prints 10? I see to be getting confused on the function in function aspect I think. Also what is the difference between `var x =`  and `x =`  ?

```
var x = 6;
var y = 4;
var a = function(b) {
  return function(c) {
    return y + b + c;
  }
};
x = 2;
y = 5;
var fn = a(x);
x = 1;
y = 3;
var unknown = 5;
console.log(fn(unknown));
```

Comment: `var x=` is used to declare x as a variable, and `x=` is used to change its value. 'var' is not used second time because x is already declared a variable earlier.

Comment: This is a basic example about JavaScript.How long have you learnt programming?

Comment: Where did you get this code? Did you write it, is it from a book? It's not very good code if it's from a book. I'd suggest more practice before you start writing functions that return functions. Or try deconstructing the code into smaller pieces. On a piece of paper, write out what you think the code is doing.

Comment: @VũKhanh, if it is that simple, you can explain it. I have seen many people struggle to get it right when it comes to javascript.

Comment: `var x` is where variable x is being declared and initialized and `x =` is where the value or x is being changed or updated.

Comment: when the fn(unknown) is executed these are the values of  y,b,c 
 b = 2,y = 3,c=5

Comment: One way to understand the values at each step..console logs are the right options..Created codepen - https://codepen.io/nagasai/pen/NjweQj

Comment: fn(unknown)  -> a(2)(5) -> returns 3+2+5 = 10 ...these are the values of y,b,c

Comment: Since the same function is called twice does it fill  in the first value the first time and the second value second time or does it match on the variable names?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var x = 6; 
var y = 4; 
var a = function(b) {
    return function(c) {
        return y + b + c;
    }
};
x = 2; 
y = 5; // unnecessary, meant to confuse
var fn = a(x); // creates a closure, where b equals 2
x = 1; // unnecessary, meant to confuse
y = 3; 
var unknown = 5;
console.log(fn(unknown)); // y=3,b=2,c=5, total = 10
```

Comment: The bits that are meant to confuse sure did a good job. Now that I know this is called a closure I think I understand that example a little better